# typescript error in gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, sass, gulp

im using visual studio code and it has built in type-script and its showing me 3 errors in this code:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'])
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Move the javascript files into our /src/js folder
gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/js"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Static Server + watching scss/html files

gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./src"  
    });


    gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});


gulp.task('default', ['js','serve']);
```

these are the errors im getting :

```
Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.
Type 'string[]' has no properties in common with type 'WatchOptions'.
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TaskFunction'.
  Type 'string[]' provides no match for the signature '(done: (error?: any) => void): any'.
```

these r my dependencies :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.23.6",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

i cant figure whats causing them, gulp is running if i ignore them. but im thinking something will crash or is not working properly? any help would be awesome!

Comment: What line is the error on? Can you highlight the corresponding code?

Comment: yes the first one is on this one 
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {
and then on this one
    gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], ['sass']);
and on the last one 
gulp.task('default', ['js','serve']);

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with that script and devDependencies. Do you have a GitHub link to demo?

Comment: im getting the error with in my visual studio it has a pre installed plug in that checks for errors, i dont have a github link to demo

Comment: I used VS Code 1.22.2 on macOS High Sierra to test the exact script and `devDependencies`, but I cannot reproduce the problem. The problem could be something in your code that isn't shown above.

Comment: No i don't have any extra stuff in my code, and i checked my extensions i dont have any other then the built ins